# Multicasting of packet in UnetStack

Tags: unetstack

I want to implement an opportunistic routing protocol in UnetStack to transmit a packet to more than one neighbor node. How can I proceed with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transmit to PHY frame to the `BROADCAST` address (`0`). The default address is 0, so not specifying a `to` address is equivalent.

Example:

```
phy << new TxFrameReq(data: [1,2,3])
```

will transmit a frame with bytes `[1,2,3]` to all neighbors.

Comment: I want to forward the packet to only selected neighbors (multicast), how can I forward the packet?

Comment: UnetStack only supports unicast and broadcast. You can either serially send to each neighbor, or you can broadcast and get the neighbors who don't need to packet to drop it.